# Reference request: How to construct a diffeomorphism between point clouds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

I'm interested in the following question:

Given two sets $S = \{x_1, ..., x_N\}$ and $T = \{y_1, ..., y_N\}$ each consisting of $N$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how can we construct a diffeomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i = 1,..., N$?

Surely this has been studied (e.g., see [point-set registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration)), but I am unable to find a reference explicitly building such a diffeomorphism.  It would be great if someone could point me to references on this question.

Comment: You have to assume that $n\ge 2$, otherwise the claim is false (but holds if you are allowed to relabel your points). The question itself belongs to Math Stack Exchange, where it was asked and answered several times in the past, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076639/n-transitivity-of-operatornamediffm-acting-on-a-smooth-manifold-m).

Answer (score 5):

The classical way would be to find a smooth 1-parameter family

$f_i(t)$ with $f_i(0) = x_i$ and $f_i(1)=y_i$ for all $i$.

This can be done inductively by taking $f_1$ to be the straight line, then have $f_2$ avoid $f_1$, etc.  There are other ways of constructing these paths, but this is one technique that works.

Once you have the collection $\{f_i\}$ then you apply isotopy extension.  This is a technique that takes the vector fields $f_i'$ and using bump functions you extend them to a time-dependent vector field on $\Bbb R^n$.  The flow of this vector field gives you $\phi$.  In particular, depending on which bump functions you use you will get different flows, and different maps $\phi$.

You can find the main argument, the isotopy extension theorem, in Hirsch's Differential Topology textbook.

Comment: If you have to write a proof, then most of this answer should be exchanged to "applying the Moser trick".

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: I had not heard of "the Moser trick".  I think the Isotopy Extension Theorem is also something that gets skipped in many graduate educations.  It's unclear to me if either title particularly helpful without a detailed reference.  Both terms score a zero on "Google Trends".

Comment: Moser trick = reduce existence of diffeomorphism to existence of a vector field. Applications start with existence of volume-preserving diffeomorphism between two compact diffeomorphic manifolds with the same volume. It is used in symplectic topology, there is a nice proof of Morse lemma based on this trick, and problem in the question is another application. (And it has to be in every textbook in difftopology, but as far as I know it is not there.)